Is repair still necessary if each node has 100% data ownership?
My cluster has 3 nodes with replication settings as below which means all data is replicated to each node.
CREATE KEYSPACE ks_name
WITH REPLICATION = {
    'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'DC1': '2', 'DC2': '1'
}

So I'm thinking if data is stored in every node, what's the point to do repair at all?

Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

With Cassandra's distributed architecture where nothing is shared (including disk storage infrastructure), it is not unusual for replicas to become inconsistent over time.
It is a common misconception for those coming from a relational database background to think that a 3-node RDBMS cluster is the same as a 3-node Cassandra cluster. In RDBMS, you might have a 3-node cluster where data is accessible from any node but in reality the data is sitting on shared disks (SAN, for example). In contrast, Cassandra nodes have their own disks which are not shared and so can be viewed as separate database instances.
In your case, although each node owns 100% of the data and are replicas of each other, it doesn't mean that they won't ever get inconsistent at some point therefore it is necessary to run repairs regularly, at least once every gc_grace_seconds. Cheers!
